# Use fields from second table if entry already exists

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I'm working on a forum right now and I try to create an Overview with the latest reply of each threat if exists.

I got two tables, one for the first thread and one for all replies.

**TABLE1** (THREADS)

**id, board, title, text, created...**

**TABLE2** (REPLIES)

**id, board, thread, title, text, created...**

Now I'm trying to select each thread and if exist the "created" field from the latest reply instead.

So I would like to have something like:

```
SELECT a.id, a.id as thread, a.title, a.created FROM a IF entry in b with b.thread = a.id use latest b.created
```

**Here the solution (thanks to LukLed)**

```
SELECT 
a.id, 
a.title, 
COALESCE(b.created, a.created) created, 
COALESCE(b.author, a.author) author 
FROM forum_threads a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT thread, max(id) id FROM forum_replies GROUP BY thread) c on c.thread = a.id 
LEFT JOIN forum_replies b on b.id = c.id 
WHERE a.board = '".data::escape($id)."' 
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (using subselect):

```
select 
  t.id, 
  t.board,
  t.title,
  t.created,
  (select max(created) from replies r where r.thread = t.id) last_reply_date,
  coalesce((select max(created) from replies r where r.thread = t.id), t.created) last_activity_date  
from threads t
```

For bigger queries this will be probably faster:

```
select 
  t.id,
  t.board,
  t.title,
  t.created,
  rg.created last_reply_date,
  coalesce(rg.created, t.created) last_activity_date
from threads t 
left join (select thread, max(created) created from replies r group by thread) rg
on rg.thread = t.id
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to retrieve more than one field from related table, it won't be that easy:

```
select 
  t.id,
  t.board,
  t.title,
  t.created,
  r.created last_reply_date,
  coalesce(r.created, t.created) last_activity_date,
  r.author last_reply_author
from threads t 
left join (select thread, max(id) last_reply_id from replies group by thread) rg
on rg.thread = t.id
left join replies r
on r.id = rg.last_reply_id
```

This select:

```
select thread, max(id) last_reply_id from replies group by thread
```

is responsible for creating a list of last replies for thread. I assume if reply has highest id, it is also the latest.

So in this query you join threads table with this select, which contains only ids of last replies, and then with replies table.

Comment: Thanks! That works good so far, but I only get one result back but there are more than one threads in table1. So there should be more results right? 

This is my code:
"SELECT a.id, a.title, COALESCE(max(b.created), a.created) created, COALESCE(b.author, a.author) author FROM forum_threads a LEFT JOIN (SELECT thread, max(id) last_reply_id FROM forum_replies GROUP BY thread) c on c.thread = a.id LEFT JOIN forum_replies b on b.id = c.last_reply_id WHERE a.board = '".data::escape($id)."' ORDER BY created DESC"

Comment: @user2443767: You shouldn't use MAX in select statement: `COALESCE(b.created, a.created)`, not `COALESCE(max(b.created), a.created) created`.